# Does anybody know how to use the jndi just from foreign jndi factory of weblogic?

Tags: weblogic, jndi

I have configured a foreign jndi factory to which a link was according!But I dont know how to use the foreign jndi in my own application!
could anybody do me a favor???

Answer (score 0):

Pretty vague question, so pretty vague answer... Here is how to obtain a `Context`:

```
  Context ctx = null;
  Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
  ht.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
         "weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
  ht.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,
         "t3://localhost:7001");

  try {
    ctx = new InitialContext(ht);
    // Use the context in your program
  }
  catch (NamingException e) {
    // a failure occurred
  } finally {
    try { 
      ctx.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      // a failure occurred
    }
  }
```

You'll need `wl-client.jar` on the class path. More details in [Programming WebLogic JNDI](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs103/jndi/jndi.html).

PS: I am not swallowing exceptions, the documentation sample does :)